# How do I find an array that follows certain rules relative to other arrays?

Tags: python, mit-scratch

I'm doing a project for the purpose of learning more about abstraction in CS. I created a project in MIT-scratch in which four characters must have unique paths on a simple map, and not collide or pass through each other. I also want the paths to be somewhat complicated, otherwise, I could just make them all go in a circle.

To solve this problem with abstraction, I marked each of the nine possible locations on the map with a number, and control each character's path with an array which contains what map number it should be on at each interval of the cycle clock.

[image: image of nine character locations]

Using this program and some paper, I was able to find several rules for the arrays which if followed, should solve the original problem.

1. each next item in an array must be a neighbor to the previous one, including the first and last numbers in the array, to create a complete loop.

   `(1,2,5,4)` OK<sup>✱</sup>
2. two arrays cannot have the same number at the same location.

   `(1,2) (3,2)` not OK
3. two arrays cannot have a reciprocal pair at the same location.

   `(4,5) (5,4)` not OK

My question is, how would I go about creating a program that would show me all possible solution paths based on paths that I input? It could be a python program which outputs array/s, or I could create it in the scratch program along with some kind of graphical path creator. Any help is appreciated, I have no idea how to go about this.

<sup>✱</sup> There's a bit of a complication, too. In the map, 1 and 4 are neighbors, but the abstraction, they are not. This could possibly be solved using some kind of function with a list of which numbers are neighbors.

Here's the scratch project if it's helpful: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/321905242/

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should first plan out how which character can go to which spots. Afterwards, you should create a function that denies the specific character, assuming that you given all the characters different variables. Maybe that will work? P.S. remember to make a table for each character!